# Идиомы C++ (и С)

Tags: c++, c

Обратил внимание, что часто встречаются одинаковые вопросы, хоть и под разными названиями - например, о недочитанном буфере и оставшемся в нем символе `\n`. При этом одни в отверах используют `ignore`, другие - чтение по символу до `\n`. Т.е. у каждого свой любимый способ.

Еще когда-то читал у Саттера, как сделать оператор присвоения через функцию обмена.

Ну, т.е. есть какие-то стандартные заготовки, идиомы, как сделать то или иное часто встречающееся действие, и над которым новичку приходится долго ломать голову и изобретать велосипед.

Может, я говорю ерунду, но, по-моему, у каждого профессионала есть свой набор этих заготовок - может, поделитесь в ответах? Будет чему поучиться.

Если ерунду написал - извините.

Comment: В программировании каждые два из трех человек считают себя профессионалами.:) Только обычно им сказать нечего.%)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ну всегда ведь можно не использовать неудачные идиомы? Кстати, у вас я уже утянул для себя - применение `tie` при сравнении. Раньше не знал.

Comment: А я - не профессионал. Я - безработный.:)

Comment: А между прочим, если есть список литературы - то пуркуа бы, так сказать, и не па?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, что не удивительно, если полистать ваш профиль в интернете.

Comment: @0andriy  И что там такого в моем профиле в интернете, что не удивительно?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, ровным счётом ничего, а это ооочень подозрительно! ;)

Comment: @0andriy, ну почему же - можно с большой вероятностью узнать имя и город проживания :)

Comment: @int3, не только это, но за последние 5 лет -- пробелы.